# Jcombobox - subscribe to selectedItemChanged event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, event-listener

I am trying to perform an action whenever a selected item on the combobox changes. one particular scenario, when action listener is not notified, is when you reset the model on the combobox. I can subscribe with another `PropertyChangedListener` and listen when the model changes, and then extract selected item, but I simply do not understand why the selected item changed event is not raise dwhen model changes. visually your selection does change, even if you query the cobox for a selected item, it does change from `null` to some object... ANy clear olution to this, rather than using two separate listeners?

Comment: Have you tried using item listener instead of action listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the action and item listeners don't fire events when model is reset, you can fire those event by yourself by subclassing JComboBox:

```
public class MyComboBox extends JComboBox 
{
    @Override
    public void setModel(ComboBoxModel aModel) {
        super.setModel(aModel);
        fireActionEvent();
    }
}
```

But IMHO it is a bug - you should report that to the official bugzilla.

Comment: this would do but I guess I will stick eith the conventional propertyChangedListenr